# , separated values in a variable

Tags: php

I have a variable $a = 271,245,789;

```
<select name="cat" class="main" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
                    <?
                    ////////////////display category//////////////////
                    $cat_details=mysql_query("select category_id,category from category_tb order by category");
                    while($cat_data=@mysql_fetch_array($cat_details)){?>
                    <option value="<?=$cat_data['category_id'];?>" <? if($a==$cat_data['category_id']){?> selected="selected"<? } ?>><?=$cat_data['category'];?></option>
                    <? } ?>
                </select>
```

in mysql we have find_in_set for these "," separated values. How can i do this in PHP

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
if (in_array($value, explode(',', $a)) {
  // Found
}
```

OK, I know now, what `FIND_IN_SET()` does

```
$index = array_search($value, explode(',', $a));
```

At all with `explode()` you can split this CSV-string into its parts and then apply every `array`-function on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that (`$key` is the position of the `$value` within `$your_string`):

```
$key = array_search((string)$your_value, explode(',', $your_string));
```

See documentation for [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the in_array/explode workaround you could also test with:

```
function find_in_set($set, $value) {
    return strstr(",$set,", ",$value,");
}
```

Either way I would separate that out; your template is convoluted enough already. (You should really move the mysql_query out too, and provide a wrapper function which simply returns a list instead.)